# can my bot reply with a message when pinged only

Tags: discord.js

when I ping my discord bot it shows what I made it say, but when someone replies to the bot it still sends the message, I want it to reply only when pinged.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could add this into your `messageCreate`event:

```js
if (message.mentions.has(client.user.id)) return message.channel.send({ content: `My Prefix is ${prefix}` });
```

You should define your prefix first so it wont get called as undefined and for the bot to show your prefix.

**For more information about Discord.js mention: [discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/MessageMentions)**